# "Search programs and files" only searches exact matches

Tags: windows-7

I click on the Start button, then click in the "Search programs and files" box.

If I type the partial name of a program, such as "Microsof", no programs are returned by the search.  However, if I type the complete name "Microsoft", it returns the matches.

If I type "Microsoft W", the matches disappear again.

If I type "Microsoft W*" then it finds Microsoft Word properly.

My co-workers' computers do not work this way - they will find partial matches.  How do I get it to go back to finding partial matches?

Comment: windows 7 and maybe 8 , search, has many critics. Consider an alternative, like agent ransack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you changed the settings of Windows Search. Try this out:

Open the Control Panel from the Start menu, Select Folder Options
[image: Windows 7 partial search settings]

Select the Search Tab and then check the radio button Find Partial Matches
[image: Find Partial Matches in Windows Search]

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I'm not sure when I would have changed that, but I must have.